# How to check if SpannerParameter is null?

Tags: c#, .net-core, google-cloud-spanner

I am returning this SpannerParameterCollection here in C#. I want to check if the LastPurchaseDate is null (essentially no purchases yet) and if it is, return null value rather than the CommitTimestamp. How would I do this?

```
return new SpannerParameterCollection
            {
                new SpannerParameter(nameof(Person.Name), SpannerDbType.String),
                new SpannerParameter(nameof(Person.LastPurchaseDate), SpannerDbType.Timestamp,    SpannerParameter.CommitTimestamp)
            }
```

I've tried if statements and the IsNull() function, but both give me errors.

Comment: I would be surprised if "if statement" does not work. E.g. something like `if (Person.LastPurchaseDate == null) return ...; else return ...` should work. What kind of error did you get?

Comment: @HailongWen that actually does work, thank you. I realized I was trying to inline my if statement rather than do it outside the return statement